# Streamlining align/array combinations (BNF grammars)

Tags: align, amsmath, arrays

I often need to write out syntax of types, programs and so on using Backus-Naur Form (BNF) grammars.  I have taken to doing this with

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \text{\itshape Types} &\quad&
    A &\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}l@{}}
         {} \Coloneqq {} & A_1 \times A_2 \mid 1 \\
                 \mid {} & A_1 + A_2 \mid 0
       \end{array}
  \\
  \text{\itshape Programs} &&
    P &\Coloneqq \dotsb
\end{alignat*}
```

Is there a way to improve this markup?  Specifically:

- Could the `{}` following `\Coloneqq` and `\mid` be somehow moved into the `array`'s column specification?  I tried `\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{{}}l@{}}`, but that did not work.
- Could the `\Coloneqq` be moved outside of the `array`, while still aligning the `\mid`s that begin each new line with the right side of `\Coloneqq`?

Comment: It might help if you have an image showing the desired output.

Comment: `\text{\itshape ` can be wriiten `\textit{` which is a bit more streamlined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to insert an empty group at the beginning and end of cells in a column you use `>{{}}` and `<{{}}`.

However, I wouldn't use `alignat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\newcommand{\bnflabel}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newenvironment{bnf}
 {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\begin{array}{@{}r@{\quad}l@{}}}
 {\end{array}}
\newenvironment{bnfalign}
  {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
   \begin{array}[t]{@{}>{{}}r<{{}}@{}l@{}}}
  {\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bnf}
  \bnflabel{Types} &
    \begin{bnfalign}
      A \Coloneqq & A_1 \times A_2 \mid 1 \\
            \mid  & A_1 + A_2 \mid 0
    \end{bnfalign}
  \\
  \bnflabel{Programs} & P \Coloneqq \dotsb
\end{bnf}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  This has really come in handy for me.  Out of curiosity, could you explain briefly why you would avoid `alignat`?  (Not disagreeing, just trying to understand better...)

Comment: @HenryDeYoung Too complicated for the case at hand.